# achemso package not running, bibliography generates erros

Tags: achemso

I am trying to write a paper using the achemso document class for the first time. I had worked with LaTeX previously using a different document class (book) and I had only used the achemso package to keep track of the references and have the reference style as ACS requires it and I had had no issues.

When I attempted to use the document class achemso, however, I got a bunch of errors. First of all, it prompts me to the "\begin{document}" as being an error (I don't understand why) and then, after it runs everything, I am having issues with the bibliography, every time the program reads a citation, I have to click enter, and when I have 7 citations, it is kind of boring, but I actually have around 200! An then, when I go to the bibliography,  I am seeing the title of the papers, which were not supposed to be included since I am supposedly using the achemso.sty style. Can anybody help?

I am attaching a MWE to see if anybody could help me with this. This is the link to get the bibliography: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxNftlsFB4P5bEtEaVVYd2YxeFE/view?usp=sharing

```
\documentclass[journal=chreay,manuscript=review]{achemso}

\author{Author Person}
\author{Second Bloke}
\email{second.bloke@some.place}
\phone{+xxx (0)yyy zzzzzz}
\fax{+xxx (0)yyy wwwwww}
\affiliation[University of Sometown]{University of Somewhere, Sometown, Country}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} %this allows for using footnotes in tables
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{SIunits} %incompatible with package chemmacros use siunitx instead
\usepackage{textgreek}%this is to use greek letters as part of a text, no math mode
\usepackage{chngcntr}%this is to change the counter
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%This highlights rows in a column by adding \rowcolor{color} before the row, but looks bad taken from http://timmurphy.org/2009/09/06/highlighting-table-rows-in-latex/
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{4}}%. specifies a column of entries to be centred on the ..
\usepackage[format=hang,labelfont={bf},margin=1em,labelsep=period,textformat=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
  \urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{
  replace-style = \fontsize{8}{10}\rmfamily,
}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfig}

\title[Example]{Non-working Example}
\abbreviations{IR,NMR,UV}
\keywords{American Chemical Society, \LaTeX}


\begin{document}

This is an example that works, except when you are trying to add some \textsubscript{subscript} text.\cite{Pinto:2005wp, Sousa:2005ug, ElSeedi:2009wq, ElSeedi:2010uc, YANG:2012hd, Masters:2012ds, Winter:2013bg}

\bibliography{Abbreviated}
\end{document}
```

Comment: On the article titles, you have explicitly set `\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = true}` so this is not surprising. For the other errors we will need to see your log, but before you edit that in I suggest you try to minimise your package use. As well as making the log and example smaller, that's a good idea for journal submission as you should use only packages and settings you *absolutely* need for that process. For example, you do *not* need `hyperref`, should not be messing with section numbering, should not be altering `\clubpenalty`, _etc._

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response @Joseph. I wanted to use [{hyperref}] to be able to use [\autoref] and don't worry about writing: ``as seen in Figure/Scheme/Section... \{fig/sch/sec:mycode}'', but it seems that achemso does not support hyperref.I deleted some packages I was using and I don't see that error any more. However, I still get an error when I am trying to put some text as subscript by using [\textsubscript{this text}]. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The latest release of `achemso` should work with `hyperref`: what version of `achemso` do you have? On `\textsubscript`, it's not currently part of the kernel so you need `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` to use it (this will change soon!).

Comment: I have the achemso 3.8k version. Is this version also compatible with the {acronym} package?

Comment: Not really tested fully (I do warn about using any packages!), but demo seems to work.